# Manually Editing Locale for Caja

Tags: locale, internationalization

I am British, using en_GB under MATE desktop - but I HATE HATE HATE the renaming of Trash to 'Rubbish Bin' in my locale. I consider it patronising and pointless, given the internal naming of all the directories is 'Trash'.

I can't work out how to find / edit the application specific locale. I can edit the global `LC_MESSAGES`, but can't work out how to grok / parse / edit the binaries in `/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES`. It's possible that there is something fundamental I don't know about internationalisation on Linux that I'm missing.

Comment: I would recommend to ask a question on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ .

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to make only `caja` show the labels in American English, while keeping British English for other applications:

- Create the directory `~/bin`

  ```
  mkdir "$HOME/bin"
  ```
- Use your favorite text editor to create a text file named `caja` in that directory and give it this contents:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  export LANGUAGE=en_US
  exec /usr/bin/caja $@
  ```
- Make the file executable

  ```
  chmod +x "$HOME/bin/caja"
  ```
- Relogin